# Google translate API not translating some words within HTML tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-translate

I'm working with google translate API, and I've noticed that when im translating HTML it's sometimes missing the word inside the tags, and returns the original word in English, for example:

after sending :

```
 "<div>
   <span id=0>you</span> <span id=1>youth</span> <span id=2>young</span> <span id=3>your</span> 
   <span id=4>yourself</span> <span id=5>youtube</span> <span id=6>youngster</span> <span id=7>yours</span> <span id=8>youse</span> <span id=9>youthful</span>
</div>"
```

I'm getting back one span that didn't got translated , while the others are translated:

```
<div> 
<div> <span id = 0> אתה </span> <span id = 1> youth </span> <span id = 2> צעיר </ span> ...
</div>
```

is there a way to force translate the HTML tag?

**EDIT: the problem was with the Type, what I need is 'text/html'**

```
  const request = {
    parent: translationClient.locationPath(projectId, location),
    contents: [textToTranslate],
    mimeType: "text/html", // mime types: text/plain, text/html
    sourceLanguageCode: "en-US",
    targetLanguageCode: "he"
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: the problem was with the Type, what I need is 'text/html'

```
  const request = {
    parent: translationClient.locationPath(projectId, location),
    contents: [textToTranslate],
    mimeType: "text/html", // mime types: text/plain, text/html
    sourceLanguageCode: "en-US",
    targetLanguageCode: "he"
  };
```